# Name for network in which nodes only have two different degrees

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, network

What is the name for a network that only admits two different values for the degrees of its nodes?

For example you might have a graph with degree sequence, $D=(12^4,4^{100}).$ The notation means there are four nodes of degree $12$ and $100$ nodes of degree $4.$ I plotted the degree distribution and got two points, so does that mean there is a linear relationship? Are these networks studied?

The degree distribution for a random network looks like a bell-curve, and for a scale-free network it looks like a power law distribution, but I have not heard of a degree distribution that has an indirect linear relationship.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't describe the degree sequence you have by the words "linear relationship". If you told me that the degree distribution is linear, I'd expect that in some range (such as $[4,12]$) all possible degrees are possible, and the frequency with which we get any particular degree changes linearly. This should be a special case of a power-law distribution.

If we just have a bunch of vertices of degrees $4$ and $12$, that's not what you'd expect to be an emergent property of any random graph law: you expect that the graph was deliberately chosen to have this degree sequence.

It's possible to choose a uniformly random graph with a given degree sequence via the [configuration model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_model). (Not that your graph necessarily looks like a typical random graph of that degree sequence.)

Answer (score 1):

Such [random graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_graph) are well studied.

Here's one meeting your specifications:

[image: Random graph with OP's specification]

Of course this is a random graph because the particular connection matrix is not constrained by the vertex degree specifications... so any particular instance is chosen pseudorandomly from all consistent such graphs.

For instance, here are four undirected graphs each having $2$ vertices with degree $12$ and $10$ vertices with degree $4$.  You can tell they are not isomorphic by counting the self-loops in each (or doing a deeper statistical analysis).  The presentation (generation) of any particular *one* of these is thus a pseudorandom process.

[image: Four random graphs]

There are many different models for generating random graphs based on the statistical distribution of nodes, or vertices, or other constraint property, as you can read in the linked site or any [book on random graphs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107118506).

Comment: I don't understand why it's a random graph. Don't random graphs exclude hubs?

Comment: So no matter how large the degree grows for the $4$ hubs it's still a random graph? For example say the $4$ hubs had degree $100$ instead of degree $12$

Comment: If you put on sufficient constraints, then there may indeed be just a single satisfying graph.  But this is an extreme case.  It is like picking a random integer between $0$ and $100$ (which everyone agrees is a random process) but then restricting a search to between $0.5$ and $1.5$.  *Technically* random, but the output is in fact a constant.  Whether your stated condition restricts the graph completely depends on the precise conditions.  Study the enormous literature on random graphs to learn more.  I suspect the *larger* the graph, the harder it is to restrict, and hence it remains random.